# Consider $n \times n$ graph paper where $n$ is a natural number

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Consider $n \times n$ graph paper where $n$ is a natural number. Consider the right-angled isosceles triangle whose vertices are integer points (i.e. points for which both the coordinates are integers) of this graph and whose perpendicular sides are parallel to the $x$- and $y$-axes. If the number of such triangles is
$$\frac{2(n+1)(2n+1)}{k}$$
then the numerical quantity $k$ must be?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. Please check https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Comment: With $n=0$ there is only one triangle, thus $k=2$.

Comment: @Somos $k$ varies. Try this in $2 \times 2$ or $3 \times 3$ grid.

Comment: Also $n = 0$ is not a valid case. $n = 1$ will have $4$ such triangles.

Comment: What is $\,n\times n\,$ graph paper? Is the numerical quantity $\,k\,$ a fixed constant that does not depend on $n$?

Comment: What is $n\times n$ graph paper? Do we have $n^2$ unit squares or $n^2$ lattice points?

Comment: @ChristianBlatter The way I understand, it is $n \times n$ grid along $X$ and $Y$ axes. So there are $n^2$ unit squares.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any square with integer coordinates and sides along $X$ and $Y$ axes, you can have $^4C_3 = 4$ isosceles right-angled triangle with conditions $(i)$ vertices having integer coordinates $(ii)$ Perpendicular lines along $X$ and $Y$ axes.

Now the problem reduces to finding the number of squares in $n \times n$ grid.

For length $1 \le i \le n$ where $i \in \mathbb Z+ \,$, you will have $((n+1)-i)^2$ squares. You can draw and try this in $2 \times 2$ grid.

So total number of squares $= \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n} (n-i+1)^2 = \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n} i^2 = \dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$

Total number of right angled isosceles triangles meeting conditions mentioned above $= 4 \times \dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} = \dfrac{2(n+1)(2n+1)}{(3/n)}$

So $k = \dfrac{3}{n}$ in your question.

Comment: thanks a lot math lover for a good explanation to my question

Comment: @victor glad that it helped you.